# Execute code on main thread in Android without access to an Activity?

Tags: android, multithreading

I have an Android service that starts and maintains a background thread.

From time to time, the background thread needs to do a callback on the main thread. I'm stumped as to how to do this.

I can't call this.runOnUiThread because "this" is an instance of Service, not Activity, and a Service doesn't have the runOnUiThread method.

I also can't create or execute an AsyncTask, because the documentation for AsyncTask says that both the constructor and the execute method must be invoked from the UI thread.

Do I need to maintain a reference to the activity that is using the service and call its runOnUiThread method, or is there another way to run something on the UI thread?

Thanks.

Comment: "the background thread needs to do a callback on the main thread" -- why?

Comment: The user of the service is an activity. It needs callbacks on the main thread so it can update UI elements. I suppose I could call it back on the background thread and make it responsible for scheduling a UI thread callback, but it would be more convenient for the consumer of the service if I could do it.

Comment: @Cruceo: Oh, heavens no.

Answer (score 78):

I'm using following code from time to time if I do not hold direct access to Activity (for a reason or another);

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(mYourUiThreadRunnable);
```

Comment: I thought it may be outdated, but still in late 2015 this is the recommended way: http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

Answer (score 7):

For Kotlin:

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post { 
    /*My task*/ 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you code in Kotlin you can use **coroutine** with *Main* dispatcher:

```
private fun runOnUiThread(block: () -> Unit) {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch { block.invoke() }
}
```

Of-cause coroutines should added to your project as a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Your activity <strike>has to</strike> *can* bind to the service.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Specifically, take a look at creating a Messenger on that page. The client activity can give a messenger object that responds to messages from the service, and once received, run whatever UI code is necessary on the UI thread using a handler.

**DO NOT** keep the activity's reference in the service. This can lead to all sorts of memory issues.

Comment: While `Messenger` is a fine solution, you do not have to bind to the service to use it. `Messenger` is `Parcelable` and can be sent in an `Intent` extra in a command sent via `startService()`.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. See [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). You can give to your service a handler object and when service needs to run some Runnable task on UI thread just must call handler.post(some_runnable_task). This call. Can find a example in this [link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html) 4.Tutorial: Handler.

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin, you should use a **coroutines** to handle threading. Coroutines also give easy access to switch context. Coroutines don't need activity reference or context.

The below code shows how you create a coroutine to perform background tasks.

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    // perfrom background work in it
}
```

The below code shows how you can switch context or move to the main thread.

```
withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
    // perform task on main thread
    }
```

Below is combine example

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        // perfrom background work in it

        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            // perform task on main thread
        }
    }
```

You can also call function to run on main thread by making it suspend

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        // perfrom background work in it
        abc()
    }


 suspend fun abc() {
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        // perform task on main thread
    }
}
```