# Cannot resolve symbol GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API.. Google sign-in in my app, Unable to access variable Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API

Tags: android, oauth, android-googleapiclient, google-signin

I've been integrating Google Sign-In into my Android App.
I have been following the Android tuorial from Google.
(https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in)
During the process I encountered this problem.

// Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
// options specified by gso.

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
    .build();
```

**Cannot resolve symbol GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API**
This is the problem I'm facing.

I've been strictly following all the steps as described in the above mentioned link. All the dependencies and plug ins are all same still the issue exists. How can I resolve this issue and move forward? Any answers will be highly appreciated..

***************UPDATE***************
**This is my app gradle**

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.cloudtree.glue'
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.2"
        renderscriptTargetApi 19
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            lintOptions {
                disable 'MissingTranslation'
            }
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/apache-mime4j-core-0.7.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.2.1.jar')
    compile project(':volley')
    compile project(':mediapicker')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**This is my project gradle**

```html
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: paste your gradle file

Comment: refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33773166/cannot-resolve-symbol-auth-for-google-integration-in-android-studio)

Comment: please add here your app level gradle.

Comment: please provide your Gradle file or clean your project and re-build project again

Comment: @ND1010_ why clean gradle

Comment: @ratilal chopda please real my comment very carefully i wrote "please provide your Gradle file or clean your project and re-build project again"

Comment: I've added the gradle files..

Comment: add this in your gradle file           compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'

Comment: In Project gradle or app gradle?? @NileshRathod

Comment: i app gradle my friend

Comment: Done. But still not working..

Comment: Remove compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0' and paste compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'

Comment: Hurrayyyy... It works for me.. This above comment.. Thanksss @ND1010_...

Comment: But another issue popped up friend.. **Cannot resolve runOnUiThread..  While importing **`import static com.google.android.gms.internal.zzhu.runOnUiThread`

Comment: is a run time error or Compile time 
if is Runtime then provide stack tress

Comment: Above issue fixed.. This link helped me.. [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198872/execute-code-on-main-thread-in-android-without-access-to-an-activity

Comment: All issues fixed.. Thanks to everyone here especially @ND1010_ for all ur valuable help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Replace your gradle dependences with this and let me know in case of any query**

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.2.1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.2.1.jar')
compile files('libs/apache-mime4j-core-0.7.2.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.2.1.jar')
compile project(':volley')
compile project(':mediapicker')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'
```

Comment: OK then please kindly refer tutorialspoint.com, developer.android.com and learn, follow strictly i m sure u will find solution from them.

Comment: Removed `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'` and added `com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0` that worked for me.. Thanks @ND1010_..

Comment: welcome bro if in case of any query the free to tell

Answer (score 0):

**update your gradle file**

```
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
```